# Python Coroutine(Asyncio) - How to?

Tags: python, coroutine

Let's say I want to print `"Main"` before printing `"Foo"`.
In Lua, it can be achieved with this code:

```lua
local function sleep(sec)
    local start_sleep = os.clock()
    while os.clock() - start_sleep <= sec do
    end
end

local function foo()
    sleep(2)
    print("Foo")
end

local function main()
    coroutine.wrap(foo)()
    print("Main")
end

main()

--[[ 

// Output:

Main
-- waits 2 seconds
Foo

]]
```

But if I try to implement it in Python it does:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("Foo")

def main():
    asyncio.run(foo())
    print("Main")

main()

"""
// Output:

-- waits 2 seconds
Foo
Main

"""
```

As I am really a beginner at Python, I would like to know how could I achieve it with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asyncio.gather()` to run coroutines cuncurrently:

```py
from asyncio import gather, run, sleep


async def aprint(*args, **kwargs):
    return print(*args, **kwargs)


async def foo():
    await sleep(2)
    await aprint("Foo")

async def main():
    await gather(
        foo(),
        aprint("Main")
    )

run(main())
```